# Image of an open set in complex analysis

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is it true that the image $f(D)$ of any open set $D$ $\subset$ $X$ is open? Here $f$ is a continuous function, and $X$ is a topological space. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: In your title you are referring to 'complex analysis'. It is not clear how your question relates to that.

Comment: The usual hypothesis is that $D$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb C$, and $f:D\to\mathbb C$ is differentiable (and, of course, nonconstant). It is definitely NOT enough to assume only continuity of $f$ (as $z\mapsto \operatorname{Re}z$ shows). Try googling this, you will get an immediate answer.

Comment: @MPW, I did googled this problem but found nothing concrete to lean on. That was why I posted the question here with the hope that someone can assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false, take $x\mapsto x^2$ for example, is continuous and mapping the open interval $(-1,1)$ to $[0,1)$, which is clearly not open. Since your title asks about complex analysis, there is the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) which states that **non-constant holomorphic** maps are indeed open, that is they map open sets to open sets.

Comment: @m1k, so can we say this is same as proving the open mapping theorem?

Comment: Only if you misread the problem and it stated holomorphic functions, as I said your initial statement simply is not true.